# Tooltip box with arrow when I using a mouse to hover a profile picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a tooltip box which involve personal introduction text,my target is a tooltip box with Arrow is displayed if I using a mouse to hover a profile picture......... I have tried some methods online but they are not workable ...... can anyone help me?

```css
.tooltip {
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
   border:1px solid #333;
   background-color:#161616;
   border-radius:5px;
   padding:10px;
   color:#fff;
   font-size:12px Arial;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td><img src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/2/26/Andrew.PNG" width="200" height="200" class="masterTooltip" title="Name: Ching Yuet To; 


Hobby: Hiking, Watching movie;

I believe that it would be fun that we can carry out research study 
independently. I think it is meaningful to participate and promote synthetic 

biology research.

I can learn a lot and make many international friends in Boston! "></td>
```

Comment: your css class is tooltip but you are using class="masterTooltip"

Comment: I don't see any cursor in your css .... use something like cursor: help;

Comment: You probably shouldn't put that much data into an html attribute... it's going to make maintenance / readability a pain unless using some template engine that is putting that there. Not to mention possible breakage if the text ends up using a quote within the text.

Comment: @Just_Do_it Could you help me in more detail ?

Comment: @Farhad Bagherlo But the arrow still not display with the tooltip box ..... ;(

Answer (score 0):

Like stated in my comments above, your css class is tooltip but you are using class="masterTooltip" plus the cursor type is missing as well.

Just check the following code, it works, you can modify to suit your needs:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  .tooltips {
   border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000; color: #000000; outline: none;
   cursor: help; text-decoration: none;
   position: relative;
  }
  .tooltips span {
   margin-left: -999em;
   position: absolute;
  }
  .tooltips:hover span {
   border-radius: 3px 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
   position: absolute; left: 1em; top: 2em; z-index: 99;
   margin-left: 0; width: 210px;
  }
  .classic { padding: 0.5em 1em; }
  * html a:hover { background: transparent; }
  .classic {background: #007DC3; border: 1px solid #FFAD33; color:#fff;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td><a class="tooltips" href="#"><img src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/2/26/Andrew.PNG" width="200" height="200" title="">
<span class="classic">Name: Ching Yuet To; 


Hobby: Hiking, Watching movie;

I believe that it would be fun that we can carry out research study 
independently. I think it is meaningful to participate and promote synthetic 

biology research.

I can learn a lot and make many international friends in Boston! "></span></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Answers with only code dumps are not helpful in teaching. Explain what you added / changed, why these additions/changes should work, etc.

Comment: I have already stated that in my comments, will update my ans as well with them

Answer (score 0):

You can change how it is displayed and consider a steady location alongside the photo to display the "Tooltip"

```js
$(".masterTooltip").on("mouseover",function(event){
  $(".tooltip").remove();
  var TooltipTitle=$(this).attr("Tooltip-title");
  var tooltip=$("<span/>",{class:"tooltip",html:TooltipTitle,css:{top:event.pageY,left:event.pageX}});
  $("body").append(tooltip);
  tooltip.fadeIn();
});
$(".masterTooltip").on("mouseleave",function(event){
    $(".tooltip").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
display:none;
   position:absolute;
   border:1px solid #333;
   background-color:#161616;
   border-radius:5px;
   padding:10px;
   color:#fff;
   font-size:12px Arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td><img src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/2/26/Andrew.PNG" width="200" height="200" class="masterTooltip" Tooltip-title="Name: Ching Yuet To; 


Hobby: Hiking, Watching movie;

I believe that it would be fun that we can carry out research study 
independently. I think it is meaningful to participate and promote synthetic 

biology research.

I can learn a lot and make many international friends in Boston! "></td>
```